# C++ MFC Integer Textfields Always Set to 0?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, initialization, integer

I'm creating a preferences form in VC++ MFC, and I have several textfields that only accept integers. I'm new to MFC, so this is how I found to initialize them in some tutorial:

```
CProgramDlg::CProgramDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
: CDialog(CProgramDlg::IDD, pParent)
, m_nSampleValue1()
, m_nSampleValue2() ... m_nSampleValueN {}
```

This is grand and all, but when I run it, all of the textboxes are filled with zeros. I know with strings that you can just send it "" and it will clear the textbox, but I tried NULL for my ints and did not have any luck.

Is there a trick to getting the textboxes to just be empty without showing zeros? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`m_nSampleValue1()` and `m_nSampleValue2()` are value-initialized. If its primitive types, then that means they will be zero-initialized.

> Is there a trick to getting the textboxes to just be empty without showing a 0?

If its integral type, then I think that isn't possible without changing other part of the code (which part? you've not posted it here).  If you don't want to do that, or if that is hard to do, then you can change the *type* of the members to string, then they will be empty strings automatically.

---

However, if you want to see non-zero values, then do this:

```
CProgramDlg::CProgramDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
: CDialog(CProgramDlg::IDD, pParent)
, m_nSampleValue1(100)
, m_nSampleValue2(200) ... m_nSampleValueN(1000) {}
```

Comment: So how is it that the textboxes are showing zeros? Is there a way to just make them empty when the program is launched?

Comment: @Jon: Change the datatypes to  string type.

Comment: It sounds like I'll just have to change them to strings and then convert the strings to integers, unless someone else can think of a better solution. Thank you for the help Nawaz!

Comment: One last question: I'm confused as to what you mean by changing the "type" of the members to string. Do you just mean changing my declarations from _int_ to _string_? Won't this mess things up later when I try and use the members as %d?

Comment: @Jon: By that I mean datatype of the member variables such as `m_nSampleValue1` etc. No it would mess things up, you've to code accordingly then. Its just that you've know how to convert string to int.